# Application of the splitting lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I am trying to understand the article "Chains of maps between indecomposable modules" by D.Eisenbud and J.A. de la Peña and I came across this:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M_1,...,M_s$ be $R$-modules and let $f_i: M_i \rightarrow
> M_{i+1}$ be non bijective module homomorphisms $\forall 1\leq i \leq s-1$.
>
> For a $1\leq j \leq s-1$ let $f_j:M_j \rightarrow M_{j+1}$ additionally be injective. Further suppose that $g:=f_sf_{s-1}...f_j: M_j \rightarrow M_s$ is an isomorphism.
>
> It follows that $\ell(M_j) > \ell(M_{j+1})$

Now apparently $f_j$ is a split monomorphism and we get that $M_{j+1}$ is decomposable. I absolutely have no clue how we can conclude that. Maybe somehow apply the Splitting Lemma?
Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: What is $\ell$ above?

Comment: @Mohan oh sorry! $\ell(M)$ refers to the length of the module $M$

Comment: Are you assuming the modules are of finite length ?

Comment: @Mohan yes that is also assumed

Comment: If $f_j$ is injective $\ell(M_j)\leq\ell(M_{j+1})$. So, I am confused.

Comment: @Mohan this fact can be shown, I think. I proved it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3855417/length-of-modules-given-an-injective-module-homomorphism

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113868/discussion-between-mathstudent-and-mohan).